# Rails datetime - insert current year when updating date with missing year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

On my page I'm using the jquery datetimepicker to get a date and time from the user. When the user selects a datetime, the format of the datetime I get is, for example: "Fri, Sep 21, 1:00PM". I do not get the year since also getting the four digit year makes the whole thing too long for the textbox.

When I pass this date (which is Fri, Sep 21, 1:00PM) back to my controller, and use the update_attributes to update the date in the database, the date that gets inserted is, "0000-09-21 13:00:00.000000". The year becomes 0000 since I was missing the year in the date. I want 2012 obviously. Any ideas how I can achieve this? Please note that I don't want to hardcode 2012 but want it to pick up the current year. Thanks.

Comment: which database you are using? can you please post some code of update_attributes function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
1.9.3p194 :012 > require 'date'
 => true

1.9.3p194 :013 > d= DateTime.parse("Fri, Sep 21, 1:00PM")
 => #<DateTime: 2012-09-21T13:00:00+00:00 ((2456192j,46800s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

you will get current year.